Did Aristotle think that essence and existence were distinct?
Did Aristotle think that essence and existence are the same thing or that they are different things? Are there references that could help me understand how he saw the difference?

That they are different. They are separate bodies because one requires the other to be prior.

See A's Metaphysics

This might shed some light, incl. pdf : re. What are the potentiality and actuality? i.e. energeia (idea, essence) and dynamis, entelecheia (thinghood, existence).
